# Finding Min and Max of list generated from CSV file Python

Tags: python, list, csv, max, min

I am trying to find the MIN and MAX values for each row of a CSV file and append them to the next position in the list, positions 5 and 6. I have managed to calculate the average, append this to the forth position and output this in highest to lowest however, I am struggling to work out how to find the MAX and MIN values of each row so I can do the same - highest to lowest. The original CSV is formatted: Fred,56,78,99 with each user on a new line.

Any help would be appreciate.

```
import csv
import operator

sample  = open("sampleData.txt", "r")

csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter = ',')

sort = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(0))

for i in range( 0, len(sort)):
    sort[i].append((int(sort[i][1]) + int(sort[i][2]) + int(sort[i][3])) / int(len(sort[i])-1))   
sort = list(reversed(sorted(sort,key=operator.itemgetter(4))))
for i in range( 0, len( sort ) ):
print(sort[i][0], round(sort[i][4]))
```

Comment: Perhaps the built-in [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) functions will be useful to you.

Comment: `sort` is a builtin function, please don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Well, `sorted` is a builtin function but `sort` isn't. One might argue that `list.sort` is a built-in method of a built-in class, but then the usual "you can no longer access the original functionality" argument doesn't apply.

Comment: I have tried using the built in min and max functions but some how I need to exclude position [0] as it includes the name.

Comment: You can use list slicing syntax to exclude the first element. `list[1:]` will give you from the 2nd element of the list to the end.

Comment: How would I amend the code to use the max function and slicing syntax to find the largest number in the list. I assume I can rewrite this line some how?     sort[i].append((int(sort[i][1]) + int(sort[i][2]) + int(sort[i][3])) / int(len(sort[i])-1))

Comment: Fair point, @Kevin. But it's still a bit confusing to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

sample  = open("sampleData.txt", "r")
csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter = ',')

sorted_list = []

for line in csv1:
    print '-- ORIG:', line
    tmp = sorted( [int(i) for i in line[1:]], reverse=True )  # eg: [99,78,56]
    stat_list = [round(sum(tmp)/float(len(tmp)), 2), min(tmp), max(tmp)]
    sorted_list.append( [line[0]] + tmp + stat_list )

for s in sorted_list: print '** NEW: ', s # has ['Fred',99,78,56,78.0,57,99]
```

You can use/modify the quick & dirty solution above. Note:

1. The result is a list of lists with digits converted to integers.
2. The float() is needed for computing average - just doing it on the denominator is enough for the whole result to be a float.
3. List comprehensions are great shortcuts and efficient for avoiding for loops.
4. The **numpy** module has builtin mean() function (among many others) that are useful and fast, especially for large arrays.

### OUTPUT (space added)

- ORIG: ['Fred', '57', '78', '99']
- ORIG: ['Wilma', '96', '4', '105']
- ORIG: ['Bar', '23', '88', '65']
- NEW:  ['Fred', 99, 78, 57, 78.0, 57, 99]
- NEW:  ['Wilma', 105, 96, 4, 68.33, 4, 105]
- NEW:  ['Bar', 88, 65, 23, 58.67, 23, 88]